# Notation for the solution to $y^y=x$.

Tags: notation

Let $x$ be a positive real number.

- The solution to $y+y=x$ is written
  $$y=x/2.$$
- The solution to $y\cdot y=x$ is written
  $$y=x^{1/2}.$$
- Is there a notation for the solution to $y^y=x$?

Answer (score 7):

There's a well known function called the Lambert W function, defined to be the inverse of $xe^x$. If $y^y = x$, then
$$\ln(y)e^{\ln(y)} = y\ln(y)=\ln(x) \implies$$
$$\ln(y) = W(\ln(x)) \implies$$
$$y = e^{W(\ln(x))}$$
I don't know of any function simply defined to be the inverse of $x^x$, though, but problems like this can often be solved with the W function.

Note: $xe^x$ and $x^x$ aren't injective on $(0,\infty)$, so you have to be careful about the possibilities of multiple solutions to these equations.

Answer (score 1):

Take logs:
$$y\ln y=\ln x=\ln y\cdot e^{\ln y}$$
The definition of the Lambert W function satisfies
$$W(\ln x)e^{W(\ln x)}=\ln x$$
Therefore
$$W(\ln x)=\ln y$$
$$y=e^{W(\ln x)}=\frac{\ln x}{W(\ln x)}$$
Any expression that relates an exponential of a variable with a linear function of the same variable is amenable to solution via Lambert W. Indeed, such expressions pop up in many physics equations, especially those relating to quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

As other's have stated, the $W$ function yields the correct answer to the question you asked.  A related sequence is this:
$$2+y=x\implies y=x-2$$
$$2\cdot y=x\implies y=x/2$$
$$2^y=2\uparrow y=x\implies y=\log_2(x)$$
$$\underbrace{2^{2^{2^{\cdot^{\cdot^\cdot}}}}}_{y}= 2\uparrow \uparrow y=x\implies y=\text{slog}_2(x)$$
where $\text{slog}$ is a superlog:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-logarithm